# Cant install Visualruby

Tags: ruby, compiler-errors, rubygems

I try to install Visualruby (`sudo gem install visualruby`) on Linux Mint I have already install ruby and Glade but its give me anytime this error output:

```
rbglib.c: In function ‘rbg_scan_options’:
rbglib.c:905:56: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘PRIsVALUE’
                      "options must be Hash or nil: %+" PRIsVALUE,
                                                        ^
rbglib.c:906:22: warning: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Wformat=]
                      original_options);
                      ^
make: *** [rbglib.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/glib2-3.0.8 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/glib2-3.0.8/ext/glib2/gem_make.out
```